# Display a list of posts belonging to a particular term when the taxonomy name is unknown

Tags: wordpress, custom-taxonomy

How do I display a list of posts belonging to a particular term? I have a particular use case where I do not know the taxonomy to which that term belongs to.

Had I known the taxonomy, I would have used the `tax_query` parameter of the [get_posts()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) function.

So, I tried to find the taxonomy name from term name by performing a database query based on [this WPSE question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/152592/i-have-a-term-taxonomy-id-is-there-an-api-call-to-get-the-taxonomy). But then, I need the `term_taxonomy_id` for this to work. I just have the name of the term.

So, I tried finding the `term_taxonomy_id` using the term name. To achieve this, I came across the [get_term_by()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_by) function. Unfortunately, this function requires the name of the taxonomy to work. This brings me back to the point where I started.

My primary problem of displaying a list of posts belonging to a particular term when the taxonomy name is unknown remains unsolved. I'm looking for pointers in this direction.

Comment: What page is this exactly, is it a taxonomy page. Why do you not know the taxonomy name

Comment: No. It is not a taxonomy page. I'd like to implement this in a plugin I'm developing.
The user chooses the taxonomy and the term; And will be shown posts matching the criteria.
The user also has the option to choose the taxonomy as 'any'. In this case, posts matching the chosen term should be displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save term IDs instead of names. Not that *users* need to select them, but for whatever term names selected save its *ID* as information meaningful for code instead.

Since recent WP versions no longer do shared terms mayhem, it should be perfectly sufficient to work with:

```
$term = get_term_by( 'slug', 'aciform', 'category' );
$id   = $term->term_id;

// now let's do this backwards from ID alone
$term = get_term( $id ); // WP_Term... taxonomy argument optional!

// and query posts using term object
$posts = get_posts( [
    'tax_query' => [
        [
            'field'    => 'term_id',
            'terms'    => $term->term_id,
            'taxonomy' => $term->taxonomy,
        ]
    ],
] ); // array(1)
```

Comment: Thanks for chipping in @Rarst. Guess I'll have to make a few changes in my plugin architecture to accommodate this. I'll see how it goes. Marking this answer as accepted. :)